# How can i open a fragment in MainActivity with onCreate method

Tags: java, android

I created a Drawer activity, right now i have MainActivity and RegisterFragment. XML and other things are done right now i can open RegisterFragment with Navigation Drawer but how can i show that RegisterFragment when application starts?

MainActivity

```java
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }


//unnecessary code block removed

 @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Fragment fragment = null;

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

            fragment = new RegisterFragment();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_tools) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        if (fragment != null){
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.screen_area, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

As i said it working well basically i want to open RegisterFragment when application starts.

Answer (score 0):

put same code

```
 fragment = new RegisterFragment();
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
 fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.screen_area, fragment);
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

in onCreate of your activity

Comment: Tried, application does not open Edit: It does not open because i deleted "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);" code :). Now it wors well thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

       // change fragment at onCreate method
       changeFragment(new RegisterFragment());
    }


private void changeFragement(Fragment fragment){
      if (fragment != null){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.screen_area, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}


//unnecessary code block removed

 @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Fragment fragment = null;

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

            fragment = new RegisterFragment();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_tools) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        changeFragment(fragment);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```